# TabBarOptions error on react native typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm learning typescript that uses react native currently, I was writing the code in js and now changing it to tsx, but I have a slight problem on my tab bar. here's a snippet of my code :

```
return (
<NavigationContainer>
  <Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName={homeName}
    screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
        let iconName: string | undefined;
        let rn = route.name;

        if (rn === homeName) {
          iconName = focused ? "home" : "home-outline";
        } else if (rn === profileName) {
          iconName = focused ? "person" : "person-outline";
        } else if (rn === registrationName) {
          iconName = focused ? "reader" : "reader-outline";
        }

        return <Ionicons name={iconName || ""} size={size} color={color} />;
      },
    })}
    
    tabBarOptions={{
      activeTintColor: "tomato",
      inactiveTintColor: "grey",
      labelStyle: { paddingBottom: 10, fontSize: 10 },
      style: { padding: 10, height: 70 },
    }}
  >
    <Tab.Screen name={homeName} component={HomeScreen} />
    <Tab.Screen name={profileName} component={ProfileScreen} />
    <Tab.Screen name={registrationName} component={RegistrationScreen} />
  </Tab.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

the tabBarOptions is red/error, and I don't really have a clue on what to do with it.
I'm hoping anyone can help me solve this here

I tried on searching the solution to the problem but can't seem to get the explanation

this is the error I'm facing

```
Type '{ children: Element[]; initialRouteName: "Home"; screenOptions: ({ route }: { route: RouteProp<RootStackParamList, keyof RootStackParamList>; navigation: any; }) => { ...; }; tabBarOptions: { ...; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<DefaultRouterOptions<string> & { id?: string | undefined; children: ReactNode; screenListeners?: Partial<...> | ... 1 more ... | undefined; screenOptions?: BottomTabNavigationOptions | ... 1 more ... | undefined; } & DefaultRouterOptions & { ...; } & BottomTabNavigationConfig, "initialRout...'.
  Property 'tabBarOptions' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<DefaultRouterOptions<string> & { id?: string | undefined; children: ReactNode; screenListeners?: Partial<...> | ... 1 more ... | undefined; screenOptions?: BottomTabNavigationOptions | ... 1 more ... | undefined; } & DefaultRouterOptions & { ...; } & BottomTabNavigationConfig, "initialRout...'.ts(2322)

(property) tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: string;
    inactiveTintColor: string;
    labelStyle: {
        paddingBottom: number;
        fontSize: number;
    };
    style: {
        padding: number;
        height: number;
    };
}
```

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Comment: Please give more information: where you use `tabBarOptions`? Edit your question and add more code snippets

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is when you write the code in js, you have used old version of `bottom-tabs`. And when you change to typescript, you have upgraded it, so `tabBarOptions` give error, because they have already removed `tabBarOptions` props in new version.

You should read [the bottom-tabs docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator) carefully, because they made a lot of changes between versions